# How do I get the iteration number from fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I've got the following code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
<%= asset.methods %>
    <div class="container">
        <%= asset.label :uploaded, 'Attach file' %>
        <div class="input">
            <%= asset.file_field :uploaded %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

where assets is initialized by

`5.times {@comment.assets.build}`

I want to get each iteration number (i.e. 1..5) as they are displayed in the ERB (something like asset_counter)- how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view, you can loop through the assests with each_with_index:

```
<% @comment.assets.each_with_index do |asset, index| %>
    <% f.fields_for :assests, asset do |asset_fields| %>
    ...
```

The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) has some nice examples too.